# Iterating through a nested table/spreadhseet

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas

Not sure how to go about getting started.  I have many tab delimited files that I want to be able to put into a database.  However the hard part is that the table is not laid out in the best way.  For example the parent row will have will be designated a letter (D) then the rows under that parent corresponds to the the parent until the next D row is listed

Ideally I want all the child rows in the same row as the parent. In order to put it into a database and query results (unless there is another way)

Here is link to the data:  http://www.gasnom.com/ip/vector/archive.cfm?type=4

Better visual representation of the data before anyone mentions it, I cannot scrape the html data as this is the only data file that has a corresponding web site.

http://www.vector-pipeline.com/Informational-Postings/Index-of-Customers.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think this works. It simply adds a list of "child" lines at the end of each "parent" line in a list of "parent" lines.

```
customer_file = open('index_of_customers.txt', 'r') # you should of course do more try-except stuff in your script
database = []                                       # all data ends up here
for each_line in customer_file:                     # reads one line at a time
    each_line = each_line.strip('\n')               # removes newlines
    each_line = each_line.split('\t')               # split the line of text into a list. This should save any empty columns aswell
    if each_line[0] == 'D':                         # if line starts with a single D
        each_line.append([])                        # add a list for the other lines at the end of the D line
        database.append( each_line )                # add a D line to the "database" as a list
    else:                                           # if line don't start with a single D
        if len(database):                           # the first line is not a D line, so we need to check if the database is empty to avoid errors
            database[-1][-1].append(each_line)      # add the line to the last D line's list. 
for each_D_line in database:                        # prints out the database in an ugly way
    print( str(each_D_line[:-1]) )                  # first the D lines
    for each_other_line in each_D_line[-1]:
        print( '\t' + str(each_other_line) )        # then each other line
```